# How to encrypt oracle db connection password using VBA

Tags: oracle, vba, tns

I am currently maintaining an excel file with a great amount of oracle db connection information, including database name, server, port, user name, password, etc...I am trying to develop a VBA macro to export all db connection information into XML format, which could be imported directly into Oracle to get everything updated easily.

Here I have a question regarding to password encryption in this VBA macro. Knowing that password in the excel file is not encrypted, I want to make them encrypted in the exported XML file. I think I should encrypt password the same way as Oracle does, so that once XMl file generated from excel and imported in Oracle, Oracle can decrypt it correctly.

So I would like to know  how oracle encryption works for password. Also, is there any corresponding function in VBA that would do the trick directly ?

Thanks

Comment: another approach is to connect with a user who only has select on the appropriate tables

Comment: see DBMS_CRYPTO package: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_crypto.htm#BJFCGDIC